# How to set width and height of gridview item in flutter with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to make a gridview in flutter to list card item in a horizontal direction with specific height and width, when I tried I always get a square cell in my gridview and no effect if I change my container height and width.

I tried like below

```
 child: GridView.count(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
            // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
            children: List.generate(cuisineListAll.length, (index) {
              return Card(
                child: Container(
                  width: 330,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Text(
                    myListAll[index].name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            })),
```

is there a way to display my card with my own fixed size? I tried flutter_staggered_grid_view but when I changed to horizontal direction, no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Another way maybe you can try `SingleChildScrollView + Wrap`:

```dart
class WrapScrollViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const WrapScrollViewPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final widgets = [
      Container(width: 100, height: 30, color: Colors.red),
      Text('111', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
      Text('222', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
      Container(width: 60, height: 50, color: Colors.orange),
      Container(width: 20, height: 30, color: Colors.green),
      Text('333'),
      Text('4444'),
      Text('555555'),
      Text('666666'),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('SingleChildScrollView + Wrap')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: ScreenUtil.screenWidth,
            height: 50,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                spacing: 8,
                crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                children: widgets,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: should be marked as correct answer... you really helped me out

Answer (score 2):

try to give `childAspectRatio: YOUR_VALUE,`

For ex,

```
...
 GridView.count(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.1,
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to create a specific card and show the grid horizontal direction. I tried this but didn't work as expected.

Comment: I need to make the card with 130 width and 100 height for each gridview item and scroll horizontally. I am just managing with listview and made a column as a listview item and added two cards, but I have to manage my data and not easy as gridview. I think if I could set the width and height for the grid view item would be a best solution.

Comment: I think there is no other solution but to use childAspectRatio, use this in such a combination that your width takes more space than height.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try :)

Comment: I am trying to solve this as well and I believe childAspectRatio is not a solution. You can make it work for a device but if you change the screen size you are screwed.